# callbacks in socket io is not working as I expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So in my client code, I'm emitting an event

```
socket.emit('new user', $nickBox.val(), (data, users) => {
//some other works
})
```

and I have a handler on my server side as

```
var users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connected')

    socket.on('new user', (data, cb) => {
        users[data] = socket
        cb(true, users)
    })

})
```

but I'm getting call stack exceeded error.

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at isArray (<anonymous>)
    at hasBinary (/Users/vigneshwar/Desktop/sio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:35:7)
    at hasBinary (/Users/vigneshwar/Desktop/sio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/Users/vigneshwar/Desktop/sio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
    at hasBinary (/Users/vigneshwar/Desktop/sio/node_modules/has-binary2/index.js:58:59)
```

*I am not seeing recursion happening more than once.*
But when I change my server side code to

```
var users = {}

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connected')

    socket.on('new user', (data, cb) => {

        cb(true, users)
        users[data] = socket
    })

})
```

It works fine. But I'm wondering why we need to call the callback function first? And why it solves the problem?

Comment: try adding semicolumns to your code `users[data] = socket;`

Comment: @Taki tried adding semicolons. But still not working.